# WebForm_AutoFocus is not being generated

Tags: javascript, asp.net, focus

I have an ASP.NET page which sometimes does not generate the expected "WebForm_AutoFocus()" javascript, even though I am explicitly calling .Focus() on one of the controls.  Are there any known scenarios where some factor would prevent that javascript from being generated?

Specifically, when the user clicks a particular button, I'm creating some new controls dynamically: in this case a text box.  In OnPreRender I'm grabbing that newly-created control and calling .Focus() on it.  The idea is, when the postback completes, the browser gives focus to the newly-created textbox control.  However, the generated HTML (verified via firebug and fiddler) simply does not contain a WebForm_Autofocus call at all.

In other scernarios, the same page (on postback or on initial hit) calls .Focus() on a different control - one which is not dynamically created; in those cases the WebForm_AutoFocus() script is generated perfectly, and all is well.

Unfortunately, I'm working on a client system that LOVES frameworks upon frameworks, and abstractions upon abstractions, so I cannot post a meaningful/concise code sample here.  However, if any of my friendly SO'ers knows more about generation of that "WebForm_AutoFocus" javascript - and scenarios which would prevent it from being generated - that would give me a good place to start digging.

Answer (score 0):

The autofocus call only gets included if asp.net thinks there is a need for it.  Set a default button on the page so that asp.net will know to make the method.